# How can I create or assign a method to temp (WindowAdapter)?

Tags: java

I want to create an instance of the `WindowAdapter` and put my method for `windowClosing` in it and then sent the temp into the `f.addWindowListener(temp)` can this be done.

Java will not let me create an instance of `WindowAdapter` like below.

```
 WindowAdapter temp = new WindowAdapter(); <-- Does not compile
```

How could this be done?

Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    setLookFeel();

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello World Printer...");

    WindowAdapter temp;


    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    JButton printButton = new JButton("Print Hello World");
    printButton.addActionListener(new HelloWorldPrinter());
    f.add("Center", printButton);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

This works but how could i use the Test() method.

```
   HelloWorldPrinter t = new HelloWorldPrinter() {
        public void test() {
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
    };

    t.test();  <-- gives a compile error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
WindowAdapter temp = new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
};

f.addWindowListener(temp);
```

**EDIT:**

About that test method. You can't do that with anonymous class (acctualy you can, but only with reflection, and that's not pretty). Because that's not what annonymous classes are for.

Annonymous classes are convinient for comfortable implementation of interface, extending abstract classes or even non-abstract ones. For example, if your `HelloWorldPrinter` class/interface had a `test()` method, then your code would compile fine and `t.test()` would call your method inside your anonnymous class.

Comment: That works but why does that work that seems so strange that you can have a constructor with { and a }; can this be done on any constructor on any class?

Comment: I suggest you read something about anonymous classes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: I didn't really want to use an anonymous class. what I am really trying to figure out is when it is better to make an instance of an interface rather than having it be implemented. I know that there are times when this is the case, and thus how would there be a benefit of making an instance of an interface like a variable rather than as a variable.

Comment: Or in this case I added a method to a class when it was instantiated with the new operator. So how could I use this method.